# Jquery Mobile after on slide pageshow not loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Am trying to show a alert message before the page loads. On home page there is a anchor tag on clicking yourPage loads but there is no alert. If i refresh the page  i can see a alert.

first page

```
<a id="transit" data-transition="slide" href="#yourPage">silde</a>
```

yourpage code

```
$( '#yourPage' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reminder : the function "live" doesn't exist anymore, it has been replaced by "on".
If it still doesn't work, you should try with the "long" version:

```
$(document).on( 'pagebeforeshow' , '#yourPage' ,function(event){ ... }
```

Comment: Are you sure yourPage is a page ?
Try $('[data-role="page"]') if it's only a page element

Comment: when i'm using "window.location", pagebeforeshow event is fired but when am using anchor tag for navigation the same event is not running.

Comment: i want to use transition and on second page i have to make a ajax call to fetch data. Any solution???

Comment: Well actually $(document).on( 'pagebeforeshow' , '#yourPage' ,function(event){ ... }); should work, so maybe the error comes from something else that prevents the event from being fired. Don't you have more code to post so that we can check ?